# How to remove iptables rule based on ip port

Tags: linux, centos, firewall, iptables

I'm trying to remove the rule that was added like this;

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport [port] -j DNAT --to-destination [ip]:[port]

iptables -A FORWARD -s [ip] -p tcp --dport [port] -j ACCEPT
```

This is working, I can use the port but when it comes to deleting the rule, I'm having issues. It just re-adds the rule and not deleting it. I have tried to use -D but still no luck. Here is the command I try to delete the rule;

```
iptables -D INPUT  -s -p tcp -m tcp --dport [port] -j DNAT --to-destination [ip]:[port]

iptables -D INPUT -s [ip] -p tcp --dport [port] -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you also need the "-t nat" entry for deletion.
Also you create a FORWARD rule and then try to delete a INPUT rule.

iptables need's to know on which table you want to delete a rule (INPUT, FORWARD, nat ? )

regards

Dirk

Answer (score 0):

This way is not the best but it worked with me without having knowledge how to work with iptables.
I will give an example of what I tried
I had this rule wanted to delete

```
-A DOCKER -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.2:3000
```

first, use `$ iptables-save` to dump iptables.

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [195:61417]
:INPUT ACCEPT [3:223]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [281:68526]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [267:67686]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A OUTPUT ! -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE
-A DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.2:3000
COMMIT
```

find where the unwanted rules are under like `*nat` `*filter` ...
for me it was under `*nat`, I copied everything from `*nat` till the rule, but don't copy it too.
then run the command `$ iptables-restore` and paste the rules you copied.
and type `COMMIT` and exit

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [195:61417]
:INPUT ACCEPT [3:223]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [281:68526]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [267:67686]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A OUTPUT ! -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE
-A DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN
COMMIT
```

if you tried to dump the rules again you will find it gone.